MongoDB - Variable WiredTigerCache
I have a question about MongoDB's WiredTigerCache variable.
When configuring an X environment in the configuration file when mentioning the:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  diary:
    enabled: true
# engine:
# mmapv1:
wiredTiger:
  engineConfig:
    cacheSizeGB: 32

A defined cacheSize value, when restarting the environment I receive the error stating that my current version does not accept any definition for WiredTiger in the CNF.
How to solve?
After the problem, I commented out the configuration file line and my system worked without any problems!

if you dont have multiple instances in same server or some very custom requirements you dont need to set this parameter at all as the mongod process will allocate half of available RAM by default to cacheSizeGB  ...

Your configuration file is not valid.
Parameter diary does not exist at all, where did you find this?
It must be like this:
storage:
   dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
   wiredTiger:
      engineConfig:
         cacheSizeGB: 32

wiredTiger is not a top-level parameter. Have a look at Self-Managed Configuration File Options before you ask any question here.
